# Serving a file to be shown in an img tag in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, stream

So I have this code:

```
downloadFile: async (req, res) => {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
    var fs = require('fs');
    mongoose.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true},).catch(e => console.log(e));
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
    var {file_id} = req.params;
    console.log('here', file_id);
    var read_stream = gfs.createReadStream({_id: file_id});
    read_stream.on('open', function () {
        var imgFile = fs.createWriteStream(`/public/images/logos/${file_id}.jpg`);
        var write_stream = read_stream.pipe(imgFile);
        read_stream.pipe(res);
    });
    read_stream.on('error', e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

And it results in this:

[image]

My question is: How can I take this res object, and send it to the view as am image to be served like this (using ejs)`<img src="<%=res.image%>" alt=''/>`. I basically want it to be a logo on a website. Users upload their logos like this:

```
uploadFile(file) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    mongoose.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true},).catch(e => console.log(e));
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    const gfs = Grid(conn.db);
    const writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: file.filename,
    });
    fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(writeStream);
    writeStream.on('close', file => {
        const {_id} = file;
        console.log(`${_id} written to the db`);
        return Account.findByIdAndUpdate(uid, {'employer.logo': _id}).then(() => res.redirect('/employer')).catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
},
```

So how can I send the image to the view to print it in an image tag?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a separate route for this. If you haven't already, install `ejs` as a dependency and add this to your entry point:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Then put a template in your `views` folder that looks like this:

```
<img src="<%= url %>" alt=''/>
```

In your route where you serve the HTML, you should build the URL to get the image from your downloadFile route, then do this:

```
res.render('index.ejs', {
    url: 'URL goes here'
});
```

If you really want to embed the image in the downloaded HTML, you could base64 encode it and put the generated text (see [here](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)), but I would not recommend that because it would slow down the initial load of your page.

Comment: Yes. My question is how to get this file form the database and save it either on the server or pass it to the view. Basically how to assign the file downloaded to a variable

Comment: Isn't that what your downloadFile route does? If you put a URL that accesses that route in the `src` attribute of an `img` tag, then the image will be loaded into the HTML document.

Comment: What my downloadFile route does is presented in the image. I cannot figure out why it's just showing it in the browser instead of saving it somewhere.

Comment: Oh, in that case you should add a content disposition header to your response like this: 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=*name*'